# Python: Sharing data between instances

Tags: python, redis, tornado

I am currently running a python application using Tornado Webserver. I use Supervisord to launch 4 Tornado instances on different ports. In front of these I am running Nginx for load balancing between the servers.

The problem is that I have implemented long-polling which means that I need for data to be shared between the different Tornado instances.

As far as I understand, when a user sends a request he gets connected to one of the tornado instances, but the callback is only saved in that single instance and data getting pushed will only be pushed to callbacks on a single instance.

How do I share the callbacks between the instances? I have been playing around with Redis, the problem here is how I save the callbacks in the key-store? Is there an easier way? Or how do I do it in Redis?

I have been looking at this thread but they don't really give me the full answer:

[Sharing data between multiple tornado instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361018/sharing-data-between-multiple-tornado-instances)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put the callbacks in redis.  Instead, you put the *data* in redis, and each process reads that data and passes it along to its own callbacks.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that makes sense. So I need to create something so that they other processes know when there is new data in Redis or in the the specific area/channel they are looking at? And then they take the data and send it to their callbacks, right?

Comment: Yes.  At small scale you can just have one channel that every process listens to, but as you grow you'll need to subdivide the data in some way.